# Is Google's Pie chart Securable?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am designing a pie chart using [Google Pie Chart](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart). I am going to host this application on the web. Is Google Pie Chart securable?

Comment: Define "securable". What do you want it to be secure from? What kind of attacks are you worried about?

Comment: I mean whether the link will be changed or it will be remain same forever?

Comment: And also whether they will keep track our data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean whether the link will be changed or it will be remain same forever?

This has nothing to do with security. You are asking if Google will continue to provide a service for all time. There is no guarantee they will, they have [disabled plenty of services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aDiscontinued_Google_services) in the past.

If you want to guarantee that a service will keep running, then you have to host it yourself.